# Showing lowest value first after one-to-one spatial join with delimiter?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, sorting, delimiter

After a spatial join (one-to-one) in ArcGIS my result looks like this: (I use a / as delimiter)

> 2015/2015/2014/2014/2013

After that i use python in calculate field to filter out duplicate values in the field:

```
def removeDup(Field, delim):  
   strList = Field.split(delim)  
   strSet = set(strList)  
   str = delim  
   conStr = str.join(strSet)  
   return conStr

removeDup(!Years!, "/")
```

So the result looks like this:

> 2015/2014/2013

Now I want to sort the values ascending in the field so it would look like this:

> 2013/2014/2015

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try sorting the list:

```
def removeDup(Field, delim):  
   strList = sorted(Field.split(delim))
   strSet = set(strList)  
   str = delim  
   conStr = str.join(strSet)  
   return conStr

removeDup(!Years!, "/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input kttii, but I still got the same result.

But when i modify your example like this it works!

```
def removeDup(Field, delim):  
   strList = Field.split(delim) 
   strSet = sorted(set(strList))  
   str = delim  
   conStr = str.join(strSet)  
   return conStr

removeDup(!Years!, "/")
```